# Truncate character strings after first N characters

Tags: r

I have a vector of strings that range from 3 characters to 59 characters. I am trying to truncate any string greater than 13 characters with "..." after 10 characters. For example if

```
a <- c("AMS", "CCD", "TCGGCKGTPGPHOLKP", "NOK", "THIS IS A LONG STRING", "JSQU909LPPLU")
```

Then I want to get

```
"AMS"   "CCD"   "TCGGCKGTPG..."   "NOK"   "THIS IS A ..."   "JSQU909LPPLU"
```

I am sure it is going to require an `if` statement and a `gsub` and my issue is the `gsub`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please share the code you have trouble with. What pattern are you using?

Comment: Based on the rules as you described, `"THIS IS A LONG STRING"` should become `"THIS IS A LON..."` instead of `"THIS IS A ..."` as in the example. That's a contradictory spec.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is already a packaged function for this operation.  Try `str_trunc()` from the *stringr* package, setting the width to 13 (10 chars + 3 dots).

```
stringr::str_trunc(a, 13)
# [1] "AMS"           "CCD"           "TCGGCKGTPG..." "NOK"           
# [5] "THIS IS A ..." "JSQU909LPPLU"
```

Answer (score 10):

Solution using `ifelse` and `substring`:

Edit (after **@G5W** comment):

```
a <- c("AMS", "CCD", "TCGGCKGTPGPHOLKP", "NOK", "THIS IS A LONG STRING", "JSQU909LPPLU")
ifelse(nchar(a) > 13, paste0(substring(a, 1, 10), "..."), a)
```

Comment: `ifelse(nchar(a) > 13, paste0(substring(a, 1, 10), "..."), a)`   would be simpler

Answer (score 7):

I think the simplest way to do that is by using `substr`, that does not require any packages

```
      a <- c("AMS", "CCD", "TCGGCKGTPGPHOLKP", "NOK", "THIS IS A LONG STRING","JSQU909LPPLU")
  
 #It will keep only chars from 1-10 for each element
      substr(a,1,10)

[1] "AMS"        "CCD"        "TCGGCKGTPG" "NOK"        "THIS IS A "
[6] "JSQU909LPP"
```

Answer (score 3):

kind of faster ...

```
ifelse(nchar(a) > 13, paste0(strtrim(a, 10), '...'), a)
```