# How to set a max limit to the characters of the values that are displayed on the y-axis of a plot, through the ggplot code?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the stacked bar chart below and I would like to know if it is possible to set a max limit of characters displayed in the values of the y-axis, for example 4, and then add a "." at the point that the characters stop. For example "subcompact" should become "subc."

```
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))

g+geom_bar(aes(fill = drv), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Comment: It seems that your question has nothing to do with `ggplot2`, it's simple string manipulation: `foo <- "subcompact"; ifelse(nchar(foo) > 4, paste0(substring(foo, 1, 4), "."), foo)`. There should be a duplicate for this somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate character strings after first N characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46759358/truncate-character-strings-after-first-n-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do the replacement in ggplot code if you didn't want to alter your source data - this is a slightly different regex solution @AndreElrico 's

```
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(sub(class,pattern = "(\\w{4}).*",replacement = "\\1.")))
```

Answer (score 1):

change your variable into your desired variable before using it.

```
mpg$class <- sub("(?<=^.{4}).*",".", mpg$class, perl = T)
```

You can use regex to archive this.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the labels with `scale_x_discrete`, which means no editing of the dataset is done.

```
g+geom_bar(aes(fill = drv), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = function(x) {
      is_long <- nchar(x) > 4
      x[is_long] <- paste0(substr(x[is_long], 1, 4), ".")
      x
    }
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```